# Is it possible to call a user defined function inside SQL select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am troubleshooting an issue with user defined function in SQL `SELECT` statement.

I am aware of the following syntax to access a UDF as part of `SELECT` query.

```
SELECT dbo.udf_function(param1) AS 'Output'
```

**THE PROBLEM**

But I have a situation where I need to blend above query as part of another `SELECT` statement. Something like below. At first place I know this is not possible as SQL gives error seeing below query as having a sub-query which is trying to return multiple columns (i.e. *)

```
SELECT 
    T1.Id, T1.Name, T1.Address, 
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_function(param1)) AS 'Output'
FROM
    table_1 T1
```

This SQL is not working.

Is there any suggestion to handle above scenario?

Comment: If your function returns a scalar value, you simply write `dbo.udf_function(param1) AS [Output]`. If it is a table function, you likely need to include it in a `CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_function(param1)) F` and then reference the fields like any other table. ...You might be able to just code `CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_function(param1) F`.

Comment: `This SQL is not working` Does it returns unexpected results or produce an error ? Please describe `not working`

Comment: No need for for subquery, @TN . Just do `CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_function(param1)`

Comment: Side point: if you do actually have a scalar function, I strongly recommend you change it to an *inline* Table function (of the form `RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT ...`) as it performs much better

Answer (score 3):

There are two scenarios :

(1) dbo.udf_function(param1) returns a scalar and produces one value for each record in table :

```
    SELECT 
    T1.Id
  , T1.Name
  , T1.Address
  , dbo.udf_function(param1) from table
```

(2) dbo.udf_function(param1) returns a table and produces rows for each record in table:

```
    SELECT 
    T1.Id
  , T1.Name
  , T1.Address
  , F.udf_field_1
  , F.udf_field_2 
   from table 
   cross apply dbo.udf_function(param1) F
```